# I removed ZSH and the HUD is disappeared

Tags: command-line, 16.04, hud

I uninstalled `zsh` on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I made the mistake of not changing the shell. I tried with:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

to restore the default shell, because I cannot login in the root shell of the recovery mode, and this is resolved.

But when I open a session, the HUD is not showing. I can only see the file interface, but not the rest of the HUD. I tried to open a shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and it doesn't work. The only way to open a shell is connecting using `ssh`.

Could you help me?

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is in it's last days/hours of support life (unless you enable ESM, which will still mean you're off-topic here), so please consider upgrade - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop.
```

I hope this helps in case it ever happens to you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as answer , So people who have the same issue may this help them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers